# How to know the exact number of bits used to store the variable in memory in case of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, memory, compression, double

I am trying to know the exact bits that would be used to represent my the values that I have stored in a variable.
I am working in MATLAB and I have a 2-D array / Matrix that has some real values stored in it. Now in order to know the size of the matrix I can use the `whos` function. However, it will give me the size of the double matrix if I am not wrong that matrix is working like a container keeping my values and the fixed value is allocated by MATLAB for the double variable which is 8 bytes for each variable. So if my matrix is of say size 2 x 2 whos will give me the size 4 x 8 = 32 bytes. As my values range between 0-100 they can be represented by a single matrix too which will allocate 4 bytes per variable making the size of the matrix to 4 x 4=16  bytes. Still, this is not the size of my actual data, I want to know how many bits are used to represent values.

This I am doing because I am trying to attain a compression ratio for my data. The data is initially in logical/binary form so the size is just the number of bits. But after applying some transformations and run-length encoding, I have a matrix now but that matrix is having real values and I need to know their actual size to calculate the CR.

Comment: I don’t understand. If your values are stored in this way in memory, then that is their size in memory. If you want to work with bits, use a `uint8` array. Then you can do bit manipulation, and count exactly how many bytes your data occupies.

Comment: ok. I think more appropriate question to solve my problem will be "Is encoding required in Image Compression?". I am trying to calculate the compression ratio between the raster image and image on which DCT is applied, so is this the right practice for compression ratio or encoding is necessary??

Comment: This question feels heavily based on misconceptions. If you have a matrix of doubles then it uses 8 bytes per element to store each as a double. It does not matter if those numbers _could_ be represented as another type with fewer bytes. The last sentence about logical arrays is also misleading - a logical value takes 1 byte not 1 bit (try `b=false; whos b`. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you're actually trying to achieve